# Divide beamer slide into different parts?

Tags: beamer

I am creating a presentation in latex with beamer

I want to obtain a thing like this:

[image]

I am using `\pause`

and for the single "column"

```
\begin{frame}{Introduzione}

    \fbox{\begin{minipage}{7em}
            \centering
        Quantum \\
        enhanced \\
        measurement  \\
    \end{minipage}}\vspace{0.75 cm}\\
    Utilizzo \\di 
    \textbf{tecnologie
    \\ quantistiche}\\ per 
    migliorare la \\
    \textbf{sensibilità} e la\\ 
    \textbf{precisione}\\ delle 
    misure
    \pause

    
\end{frame}
```

But how can I add the second column (Quantum imaging in my example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\onslide<>{}` and `columns` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Introduzione}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
            \onslide<1->{
            \fbox{\begin{minipage}{7em}
                    \centering
                    Quantum
                    enhanced
                    measurement
            \end{minipage}}\vspace{0.75 cm}\\
            Utilizzo di \textbf{tecnologie quantistiche} per migliorare la \textbf{sensibilità} e la \textbf{precisione} delle misure
            }
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
            \onslide<1->{
            \fbox{\begin{minipage}{7em}
                \centering
                Quantum
                enhanced
                measurement
            \end{minipage}}\vspace{0.75 cm}\\
            Utilizzo di \textbf{tecnologie quantistiche} per migliorare la \textbf{sensibilità} e la \textbf{precisione} delle misure
            }
        \end{column}        
        \begin{column}{.3\linewidth}
        \onslide<1->{
            \fbox{\begin{minipage}{7em}
                    \centering
                    Quantum
                    enhanced
                    measurement
            \end{minipage}}\vspace{0.75 cm}\\
            Utilizzo di \textbf{tecnologie quantistiche} per migliorare la \textbf{sensibilità} e la \textbf{precisione} delle misure
        }
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This doesn't solve your issue with the arrow between the boxes, so you might want to consider replacing that with an animated `tikz` image.

BTW: I would generally advise against overly using `\\` for linebreaks. If you define the width of your environment LaTeX typically does this on its own.

**EDIT:** You can use a `tikz` only solution for situations like this. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}{Introduzione}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[def/.style={draw, rectangle, text width=.2\linewidth,align=center},description/.style={text width=.2\linewidth,align=center,anchor=north}]
            \onslide<1->{
                \node[def] (D1){Quantum enhanced measurement};
                \node[description,below = of D1] {Utilizzo di \textbf{tecnologie quantistiche} per migliorare la \textbf{sensibilità} e la \textbf{precisione} delle misure};
            }
            \onslide<2->{
                \node[def,right = of D1] (D2) {Quantum enhanced measurement};
                \draw[thick,->,>=stealth] (D1) -- (D2);
                \node[description,below = of D2] {Utilizzo di \textbf{tecnologie quantistiche} per migliorare la \textbf{sensibilità} e la \textbf{precisione} delle misure};
            }
            \onslide<3->{
                \node[def,right = of D2] (D3) {Quantum enhanced measurement};
                \draw[thick,->,>=stealth] (D2) -- (D3);
                \node[description,below = of D3] {Utilizzo di \textbf{tecnologie quantistiche} per migliorare la \textbf{sensibilità} e la \textbf{precisione} delle misure};               
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi thank how can I replace it with tikz?

Comment: I added an example.

Comment: Thank you so much, do you know how can I center or enlarge it ?

I have put the photo of the result and the three columns seem at the right of the page and compressed

Comment: Try `\centering` the image. Also, I should tell you that this is more of a follow-up question, which should be seperated into a new question. I added the `tikz` version, because I was the one who mentioned it in the first place and it is an alternative solution to your initial question. Also, try to make sure, you experiment with the code a bit to understand it better and find existing solutions on tex.SE that may help you before asking people here to help you.